# proc transpose to oracle sql

Tags: sas, transpose, oracle-pro-c

We have SAS logic in our applications. Our task is to replace this SAS logic with Oracle sql logic. I am trying to covert all those SAS queries to oracle queries. I stuck at `proc transpose` command. Anyone please tell me the corresponding sql query for the below `proc transpose` query.

```
FACT_ID   INDEX MACHINE SEQ   TYPE  MACHINE_VERSION SW_RELNR    HX_TSE_ID   VALUE       ID
12407319    1   5426    626 5500/1100   2            8.8.0       f00bc372   5426     f00bc372
12414338    1   5426    626 5500/1100   2            8.8.0       f00bc372   5426     f00bc372
14951471    1   5426    626 5500/1150C  3            8.8.4       f00bc372   5426     f00bc372
15045649    1   5426    626 5500/1150C  3            8.8.4       f00bc372   5426     f00bc372
10411019    1   5426    626 5500/1100   1            8.7.0       f00bc372   5426     f00bc372
12407320    1   5426    626 5500/1100   2            8.8.0       f00bc373   8.7.0    f00bc373
15045650    1   5426    626 5500/1150C  3            8.8.4       f00bc373   8.8.4    f00bc373
12414339    1   5426    626 5500/1100   2            8.8.0       f00bc373   8.8.0    f00bc373
10411020    1   5426    626 5500/1100   1            8.7.0       f00bc373   8.7.0    f00bc373
14951472    1   5426    626 5500/1150C  3            8.8.4       f00bc373   8.8.0    f00bc373
10411018    1   5426    626 5500/1100   1            8.7.0       f00bc374   02/18/2002   f00bc374
12407318    1   5426    626 5500/1100   2            8.8.0       f00bc374   02/18/2002   f00bc374
12414337    1   5426    626 5500/1100   2            8.8.0       f00bc374   03/21/2003   f00bc374
14951470    1   5426    626 5500/1150C  3            8.8.4       f00bc374   03/21/2003   f00bc374
15045648    1   5426    626 5500/1150C  3            8.8.4       f00bc374   08/23/2004   f00bc374
15045651    1   5426    626 5500/1150C  3            8.8.4       f00bc375   22:39    f00bc375
14951473    1   5426    626 5500/1150C  3            8.8.4       f00bc375   12:40    f00bc375
1
```

**Proc query is:**

```
proc transpose data=work.temp2 out=work.dataset (drop=_label_ _name_ _item_ machine_version);
by machine seq type index sw_relnr;
id hx_tseid;
var value;
run;
```

We are unable to run proc queries to see the output as SAS is not working in our system. Can anyone please provide a similar oracle sql query and the output.

thanks

Comment: Your proc tranpose code refers to a variable called `index` which is not present in the sample data you've provided. Presumably this is intended to be the input to proc transpose?

Comment: You're looking for a PIVOT clause in Oracle, though I don't know if it's as dynamic as Proc Transpose is. The Transpose flips a table from long to wide format in your code.

Comment: @user667489 I've renamed column name from IND to INDEX. can you please tell me what would be the output for the proc transpose query above?

Comment: @Reeza yeah, but we are using oracle 10g. Pivot is introduced in oracle 11.

Comment: You can download SAS UE for free from SAS Website and test it. In SQL you have to hardcode your data flip then and know in advance your column names. One of SAS best procs IMO.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the SQL query, with a giant note that the PROC will through an error in SAS if you have duplicate values for the Group by clause, whereas the SQL will simply add it up. Many people use a MAX but I like to use SUM instead since it's easier to find bugs in your data that way.

```
select machine, seq, type, index, sw_relnr,
   sum(decode(hx_tseid, "f00bc372", value)) as f00bc372,
   sum(decode(...)) as f00bc373,
   ..
   sum(decode(...)) as f00bc375
 from have
 group by machine, seq, type, index, sw_relnr
 order by machine, seq, type, index, sw_relnr;
 quit;
```

As far as I know there isn't a way to dynamically assign or determine the number of variables needed, ie how many f00bcXXXX, but my Oracle SQL skills are rusty.